# Multiple sections in tableView getting selected at a time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableheader, prepareforreuse

I have an Expanded TableView, with HeaderView containing a checkBox, a label and a radioButton.

CheckBoxes can have multiple selection. But **radioButton has only single selection**. If another radio-button is selected, then previously selected button gets deselected in tableView

My problem is, whenever I select a radio-button at section 0, then radio-button at section 8 and 16 also get selected. Upon scrolling the radio-button changes it's state. Any radio-button for any section gets selected. I am aware it is due to the cell reuse property of the tableView, But I am not getting how to solve this. I have referred to numerous solutions here on SO, but none seemed to work. This issue is really troublesome for me, because of which I am not able to proceed further. Kindly guide me if wrong or if I am missing something. Help much appreciated. Thank you!

**Here is my code for HeaderView of tableView:**

```
import UIKit
import M13Checkbox

protocol HeaderViewDelegate {
    func toggleHeader(header : HeaderView, section : Int)
}

protocol CustomHeaderDelegate: class {
    func didTapButton(in section: Int, headerView : HeaderView)  
}

class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

@IBOutlet weak var stateCheckBox: M13Checkbox!    
@IBOutlet weak var stateNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteState: M13Checkbox!

var delegate : HeaderViewDelegate?
weak var delegateHeader: CustomHeaderDelegate?   
var sectionNumber : Int!
var section : Int!

var radioButtonSelected : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if radioButtonSelected {
            favouriteState.checkState = .checked
        }else{
             favoriteState.checkState = .unchecked
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    stateCheckBox.boxType = .square
    stateCheckBox = .bounce(.fill)

    favouriteState.boxType = .circle
    favouriteState.setMarkType(markType: .radio, animated: true)
    favouriteState.stateChangeAnimation = .bounce(.stroke)
}

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView)))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder : aDecoder)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action: #selector(selectHeaderView)))
}

func selectHeaderView(gesture : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gesture.view as! HeaderView
    delegate?.toggleHeader(header: self, section: cell.section)
}

func customInit(titleLabel : String, section : Int, delegate : HeaderViewDelegate) {
    self.stateNameLabel.text = titleLabel
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}

@IBAction func selectPrimaryCondition(_ sender: M13Checkbox) {
    // get section when favourite state radioButton is selected
    delegateHeader?.didTapButton(in: sectionNumber, headerView : self)
}

 override func prepareForReuse() {
    // What do do here…??
} 
}
```

**Here is my ViewController class:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return states.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return states[section].cities.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (states[indexPath.section].expanded) {
        return 44
    }else{
        return 0.0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "headerviewcell") as! HeaderView
    var list = states[section]
    headerCell.customInit(titleLabel: list.stateName, section: section, delegate: self)
    return headerCell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subcells") as! CollapsibleCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none   
    cell.textLabel?.text = states[indexPath.section].cities[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // works for headers or cell??
}

func toggleHeader(header : HeaderView, section : Int){
    states[section].expanded = !states[section].expanded

    for i in 0 ..< states[section].cites.count {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: section)], with: .automatic)
    }
}

extension ViewController: HeaderDelegate {
        func didTapButton(in section: Int, headerView : HeaderView) {
         print("\(section)")
        }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**What I am getting:**

[image]

Comment: You need to store which indexpaths are selected somewhere.

Comment: @ZonilyJame Yes I get the Section number when radio-button is selected. But how to use it. I tried comparing previously section and current section, to change the button state, but then button does not selected next time.

Comment: Where should I write my code, In toggleHeader or `viewForHeader`. accessing buttons in `viewForHeader` don't seem to work.

Comment: Not related but `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` has no effect at all around `reloadRows` and it's much more efficient to call `reloadRows` **once** passing the array of **all** index paths.

Comment: Can add to the code your model for the `states` array?

Comment: access button in `viewForHeaderInSection`

Comment: @vadian You are right. Can you please tell me why multiple sections are getting selected ? I am about to give up : (

Comment: @Lu_ Already tried that, but it has no effect.

Comment: stop using `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView` create new header every time

Comment: @Lu_ Sorry but Can you please tell how and why? upon scrolling will the state of radio-button change?

Comment: Do you want to only section header selection or also row should be selected ?

Comment: @PaulMarshal  HI..! I have to select radioButton and checkBox in `HeaderView` and only checkBox in `CollapsibleCell`. For now selecting radio-button in HeaderView is very important

Comment: Please post image is possible. I didn't recognize your issue with only code.

Comment: @Bella, issue is due to headerView reuse. Need to store selected state of each header to handle this reuse issue.

Comment: @PaulMarshal Please check...Hope I am clear now.

Comment: @Bella could you show your model class here. You may need to add some variable to hold the selected State.

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN I have added isHeaderTapped boolean in State class and for checking if radio button selected please check the updated code

Comment: @Bella How are you deciding to show the radioButtonSelected state?. I won't see any condition over there.

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN  For that I have used boolean value `radioButtonSelected`. Please check in code. I get the radioButtonSelected selected state(true/false), when it is selected, not selected

Comment: @Bella radioButtonSelected should be set by the datasource value. Store that state some where in your model object.